# How to install a static library version using vpckg manifest files?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, vcpkg

I'm trying to figure out how to configure my manifest file to compile a static version of my library using vcpkg's new manifest feature.  My current manifest file is:

```
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version-string": "v0.1",
  ],
  "dependencies": [
    {
      "name": "curl",
      "features" : [
        "openssl"
      ],
      "platform" : "(windows & x64 & static)"
    }
  ]
}
```

but this results in nothing getting installed.  The option `"platform" : "windows"` installs for the `x86-windows` triplet, but I can't figure out the correct parameters for `x64-windows-static`.

I'm also curious -- is there a way to declare a triplet for all libraries, instead of making each library a JSON object and listing it specifically?

Answer (score 3):

You've misunderstood the manifest mode.

```
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version-string": "v0.1",
  ],
  "dependencies": [
    {
      "name": "curl",
      "features" : [
        "openssl"
      ],
      "platform" : "(windows & x64 & static)"
    }
  ]
}
```

The code above means you'll only need the lib when triplet x64-windows-static is used.

What you have to do is to specify the right triplet when configure your project.

For example for CMake projects. set variable `VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET` to `x64-windows-static` before the first `project()` directive:

```
set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET x64-windows-static)
project ("myProject")
```

For more information, consult [buildsystems](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/buildsystems/integration.md).

Answer (score 1):

As a newly released feature of `vcpkg`, `manifest` is actually under development. You could refer to Microsoft Blog about [manifest](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/vcpkg-accelerate-your-team-development-environment-with-binary-caching-and-manifests/).

Also, an example of the `manifest` on [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/specifications/manifests.md) is provided for reference.

The following is an example of an existing port CONTROL file rewritten as a vcpkg.json file:

```
Source: pango
Version: 1.40.11-6
Homepage: https://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pango/
Description: Text and font handling library.
Build-Depends: glib, gettext, cairo, fontconfig, freetype, harfbuzz[glib] (!(windows&static)&!osx)


{
  "name": "pango",
  "version-string": "1.40.11",
  "port-version": 6,
  "homepage": "https://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pango/",
  "description": "Text and font handling library.",
  "dependencies": [
    "glib",
    "gettext",
    "cairo",
    "fontconfig",
    "freetype",
    {
      "name": "harfbuzz",
      "features": [ "glib" ],
      "platform": "!(windows & static) & !osx"
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally, regarding the issue of declaring a triple for all libraries, welcome to submit this issue to [Microsoft DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).