# How to exclude a specific lib from being linked static?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vcpkg

I'm linking some libraries with the triplet windows-static:

[image]

I'm trying to exclude a specific library (`openssl`) from being linked static, while keeping all others static.

While searching around I found this [answer](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/17939#issuecomment-841969081):

> If you want to locally override the default linkage for a particular port, you would put the override into a custom (overlay) triplet file.

But i couldn't figure out how to do it.

Also, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65769727/22456056), but the links in the Microsoft GitHub throw `404 - page not found`.

Comment: Are you using Classic mode?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT classic

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT im using Visual Studio as you can see in the picture, not cmake, also im asking about linking not installing.

Answer (score 0):

There is [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/examples/overlay-triplets-linux-dynamic) for Linux. I tested it but did not work on Windows.

But, the [sample](https://github.com/Intelight/vcpkg/blob/master/triplets/x86-windows-mixed.cmake) I posted in the comment also works for Visual Studio.

You could modify the x64-windows-static.cmake  file  in folder(vcpkg-master\triplets).

Then remove openssl package and install `vcpkg.exe install openssl --triplet x64-windows-static`

It will link openssl  dll dynamically with x64-windows-static option.

cmake file Eg.

```
set(VCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE x64)
set(VCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE static)

if(${PORT} MATCHES "openssl")
    
    set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE dynamic)
else()
    
    set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE static)
endif()
```